# Shell Script loop is executing multiple times

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, sh

I have a log file. I’m doing tail -f and grep options whenever new logs are coming. I’m facing loop issue, It is executing multiple times. here is my script,

```
AuditTypeID=$""
QueryResult=$""
tail -n 0 -F hive-server2.log \
 | while read LINE
 do
   if [ `echo $LINE | grep -c "select *" ` -gt 0 ]
    then
      AuditTypeID=15
      QueryResult=$(
       awk '
          BEGIN{ print "" }
          /Executing command\(queryId/{ sub(/.*queryId=[^[:space:]]+: /,""); q=$0 }
          /s3:\/\//{ print "," q }
          ' OFS=',' hive-server2.log \
       | sed -n \$p
       )
    elif [ `echo $LINE | grep -c 'select count' ` -gt 0 ]
     then
       AuditTypeID=22
       QueryResult="$(
         grep -oE 'select count\(.\) from [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*' hive-server2.log \
          | sed -n \$p
         )"
     fi

    user=$(
       cat hive-server2.log \
        | grep user \
        | awk -F "[. ]" '{print "," $(NF-1)}' \
        | tr -d ',' \
        | tr -d 'UTC'
       )
     Additional_Info=$(
        echo -e "{\"user\":\"""${user}""\", \"query\":\"""${QueryResult}""\",\"s3Path\":\"""${s3}""\"}"
        )
    echo -e "$Additional_Info" > op.json
    for file in /var/log/hive/op.json
     do
       boto-rsync $file s3://hive-log/log/script/$file.$current_time
     done
 done
```

It will filter the operations based on the keyword. For some reason it is executing multiple times. I need to save the output for only one instance and any help to simplify the logic is appreciated.

Comment: Fix your code formatting with 4 spaces or tabs to make it readable

Comment: Did you run your script in debug mode with `set -x` to see whats wrong?

Comment: What a mess, good luck

Comment: @Inian its a loop issue

Comment: @Jeyamahesan: Ok how to do we debug this? Make your script presentable before posting in any of StackExchange communities

Comment: You have two loops, one inside the other. (A `for` loop inside a `while` loop).  In which are you seeing the problem? (And seems strange to say that a loop "executing multiple times" is a problem --- isn't that what loops are for?)

Comment: @Jeyamahesan, you could post sample Inputs and sample outputs so that we could provide better solutions too here.

Comment: Start with this: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Create a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem as what you've posted isn't Minimal. By doing so you'll probably solve the problem yourself and not even need to ask the question. See [ask].

Comment: Which loop is executing more times than you expect?  The outer one will iterate once for each new *line* added to the file, which could be a lot.

Comment: The spellcheck.net link is not working for me... It would help if you show us the output and input you want -- as small as possible... (can be posted in a pastebin) and share that inline with your question.

Comment: @MichaelBack It's not "spellcheck", it's "shellcheck" as in it checks shell. Alternatively, click the link instead of typing it in.

Comment: `if [ $(echo $LINE | grep -c "select *" ) -gt 0 ]` is a travesty.  `if echo "$LINE" | grep -q select; then` works just as well

Comment: @thatotherguy, LOL -- regardless -- the shellcheck link is blank for me.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see in your script is that in the first **awk** scriptlet inside the `if` statement you seem to be reparsing the whole of `hive-server2.log` (which is probably racy/bad because you are tailing to your script, and `hive-server.log` is growing?)... and this reparsing of the log seems to be a common theme in the script -- I think this is the root cause of the issue.

One simplification *;)* readily apparent is removal of the `elif` code -- it will never run because `/select count/` will be matched by the `if` statement's `/select */`.

To truly take a stab at simplifying this, my strategy would be to rewrite the whole of this in **awk**.  There is nothing that you are doing here that is beyond **awk**'s built-in capabilities -- and **awk** can fire off external shell commands as easily as **sh**.  The **awk** implementation will also likely be much faster.

I started trying to do this translation, but with the way you are specifying multiple reparsing of `hive-server2.log`, I frankly got lost.  Having a bit of input and intended output would help here... Please post `hive-server2.log` and your expected output.